# send HTML email using ckeditor in php

Tags: php, html, ckeditor, html-email

I am sending a html email using CKEditor using php. I am able to get mail in my inbox. but it is not in correct format. I want HTML formatted email in my inbox. Currently it is displaying HTML code as shown in the output blow. Can you help me to send a HTML formatted email using PHP or have a look on my existing code if there is any problem?
Please have a look on code and its output.

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.7/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body">
<?php if (!isset($_POST['email'])) { ?>
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">To</label>
         <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="" name="to_email">
         </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Subject</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="" name="subject_email">
       </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
       <label for="message_email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
       <textarea class="form-control" id="message_email" rows="3" name="message_email"></textarea>
       </div>
       </div>

       <div class="form-group">
       <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="email">Send</button>
       </div>
       </div>
       </form>
       <?php
       } else {
       if (!empty($_POST['to_email'])) {
       $message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message_email']);
       $subject = htmlspecialchars($_POST['subject_email']);
       $headers = '';
       $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
       $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
       $headers.="From: admin@expertsusa.org";
       $email_to = $_POST['to_email'];
       echo '<div class="row">';
       $html = stripcslashes($message);
       if (mail($email_to, $subject, $html, $headers)) {
       echo '<div class="col-md-12"> Success :' . $email_to . '</div>';
       } else {
       echo '<div class="col-md-12"> Fail :' . $email_to . '</div>';
       }
       echo '</div>';
       }
       }
       ?> 
       <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-5"></div>

       </div>
       </div><script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'message_email' );</script>
```

This code is able to send mail any email id, but its output is :

```html
<p>hi I am <strong>here</strong></p> <hr /> <p>&nbsp;</p>
```

I have tried many solutions but didn't achive results.
Please someone can tell me the solution of this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is exactly your question? There is no questionmark in this question.

Comment: My question is, why this code is displaying HTML code in my inbox? even I have added 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' as header.

Comment: why not `charset=UTF-8` or just remove it

Comment: heads up: if I passed static html value then it works fine.

Comment: $html ="<p>jaswinder&nbsp;<strong>singh</strong></p>";   so I thing the problem is here $html = stripcslashes($message);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this `$headers`

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

and use $message

```
$message = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['message_email']);
```

Comment: @Hanaa can you elaborate more about the question

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, I did the mistake here

```
$message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message_email']);
```

It should be

```
$message = $_POST['message_email'];
```